# How to avoid line wrap on hover items in menu?

Tags: css, menu, hover

I have a situation where menu items wrap to the next line when you mouse over the left column menu item or when that menu item is in the active state (meaning also bold).

These menus are created dynamically by the user when they create CMS pages and they don't like the fact that the menu wraps to the next line when it goes from off state (unbolded) to over state (bolded state).

It looks like:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a bold font-weight is larger than the non-bold. So for as long as you use bold as a :hover state for a non-bold :link you will have this problem.

There are many other ways to give user feedback without using font-weight:bold. I prefer giving feedback in ways that do not alter the size of the text like: text-decoration:underline, or using a different color for the :hover state.